# Getting started with MQ on Java: Where to begin?

Tags: java, xml, messaging, mq

I'm trying to kludge some legacy connectivity into one of our newer applications, and this marks my first foray into MQ.  We have a middleware server that accepts an XML message delivered via MQ; converts this into a proprietary request for our ancient system of record, and then delivers a response on a reply queue in a similar XML format.

I have a sample of the input and output XML structure, and the MQ host, target queue, and reply queue.  What I do not have is a clue as to where to begin.

Is there a decent tutorial available for building a simply request/response mechanism with OpenMQ or one of the other free MQ libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you first get comfortable with the [Java Message Service (JMS)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jms/index.html) concepts and [API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/jms/package-summary.html) and then concentrate on the particulars of [OpenMQ](http://mq.java.net/).

To learn about JMS, read the [JMS chapter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) in Oracle's [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html).  The [Manning](http://manning.com/) book [*ActiveMQ in Action*](http://manning.com/snyder/) gives a good introduction to JMS concepts.

If you want to simplify your JMS code, consider using [Spring JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jms.html).

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle developers guide for OpenMQ would prob be a good place to start:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1796/index.html

Gives you example code, explains how to interact with it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

WebsphereMQ has an API tester - a demo application that allows you to experiment with the API and different features from a GUI

There's a similar tool for generic JMS providers called [hermes](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home)

Comment: OpenMQ is the glassfish messaging system which is an extension of JMS.

Comment: OpenMQ is supported by hermes